# Sending data to database server in Android

Tags: php, android, android-emulator

hey guys i wanna ask a question about sending data to database to server using android app i am write script code by php like this .

```
     <?php 
            $coonect=mysql_connect("myhost of the site ","root","");
         if(!$coonect){
       echo "Data_base error";
         die(mysql_error());
         }
       ?>
       <?php
          $username=$_POST['menu_name'];
               $id=$_POST['id'];

         $db_select=mysql_select_db("TableName");
       if(!$db_select){
            die(mysql_error());
            echo" error";

     }
       $query= "INSERT INTO `DatabaseName`.`TableName` (
                   `name` ,
                    `id`
                        )
               VALUES (
                 '{$username}', '{$id}'
                        ); " ;

                  if($medo=mysql_query($query)){
             header("localhost/filename");
           exit;
               }else{
     echo"<p> Error</p>";
     die(mysql_error());
            }

               ?>

        <?php 
             mysql_close($coonect);
        ?>
```

and the code in the action buuton in  the android like this .

```
           public void postData() {
// Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
   HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
   HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://mysite/script.php");

  try {
    // Add your data
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("menu_name", "any data"));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "0345644"));
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

    // Execute HTTP Post Request
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

   } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   } catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  }
     }
```

i dont change any thing in Androidmainfest file to establish the connection do i have to and if i should put something what isit ?!! but the apk work fine but it dosent work at all do i making something wrong in my code or i should put  any permission in the Androidmainfest i dont know what's wrong ??? any Help pleas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, any network communication would require this

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

in the manifest file. But I can't really tell if it is due to this prevent you from doing your thing. Maybe after doing adding this, you could do a ping test from your android device using terminal emulator or apps like that. Let me know if you need help getting these information.

Comment: Thanks makn i will try it and tell u if every thing is alright :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you need to give the **INTERNET** permission like below in the Manifest;

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

If you are trying to run the Android program on API level higher than 13, you have to code the connecting to Internet part in a background thread not in the main thread.

If you are running it below API level 13 you no need to worry about where to code the connecting part.

PS. : This is an example for handling [HTTP POST](http://anujarosha.wordpress.com/2012/01/27/handling-http-post-method-in-android/) and [HTTP GET](http://anujarosha.wordpress.com/2012/01/20/handling-http-get-method-in-android/) in Android

Comment: Thanks Man i will try it every thing seem to be good :) i hope it will work :)